# LD_LIBRARY_PATH can be seen in os.environ() but needs to be manually appended through sys.path.append()

Tags: python, path, virtualenv, sys

I did correctly export LD_LIBRARY_PATH including the path of my virtual environment, as can be seen in `os.environ('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')`. There are several paths in the list, separated by colons, the virtualenv path is the very first in the list, so the output is something like:

```
'.../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/usr/lib/cuda/include:/usr/lib/cuda/lib64:.../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/usr/lib/cuda/include:/usr/lib/cuda/lib64:'
```

where I used the dots to omit the first part.
However, if I try to import:

```
import matlab.engine
```

which requires a very specific process to be installed, I get a ModuleNotFoundError. This can be corrected by using `sys.path.append('.../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages')`, and the matlab.engine package can be successfully imported. Any advice on how to bypass this error?

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has nothing to do with importing python modules.  `PYTHONPATH` is the variable for that.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your suggestion. `PYTHONPATH` points to `.../lib/python3.8`, which is not my virtualenv path. For some reason, any other package can be imported without the `sys.path.append()` trick, except for matlab.engine.